# Plist From URL to NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, plist, nsdata, nsurl

I have the code below:

```
//Find device directory
            NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
            NSString  *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
            //Define file name
            NSString * fileName = [file objectForKey: (id) kCFFTPResourceName];
            //File path to file
            NSString  *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", documentsDirectory,fileName];
            //Download Plist from server and write to 'filePath'
            [[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://url.net/directory/%@",[file objectForKey: (id) kCFFTPResourceName]]]] writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
            //Load Plist from directory
            NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:filePath];
            //Load Data into Array
            mapDetails = [[NSMutableArray alloc ] initWithContentsOfURL:url];

            NSLog(@"Here is the Dict %@",mapDetails);
```

My issue is, is that `array` is being returned as 'nil', what's my issue??

I've tried various combinations and still can't get the strings in the `PLIST` into an `NSMutableArray`.

Comment: When code doesn't work as expected it is best to split long lines up into many lines. Make one method call per line and assign the result to a variable. It makes the code much easier to read and debug. Split the line with 5 method calls into 5 separate lines of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[noSpaces stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"plist" withString:@""];` returns a new `NSString`. It doesn't change `noSpaces`.

Change these two lines:

```
[noSpaces stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"plist" withString:@""];

NSURL *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:noSpaces withExtension:@"plist"];
```

to:

```
NSURL *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:[noSpaces stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@".plist" withString:@""] withExtension:@"plist"];
```

**Update**: why don't you use filePath to read the content to `NSMutableArray`?

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:filePath];
```

Note:

1) `[[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource: withExtension:]` is used to find resource built into your application.
2) If the content of the file is not be able to parsed to an array, you'll still get `nil`.

This assumes the file location is correct. If what you do is load the remote URL and save the content to a plist file, then read it, you should make sure 1) the content is saved to the file successfully, 2) the path to load it is correct, 3) file content could be parsed to array.

Comment: mapDetails still returns 'nil' - sorry.

Comment: You should set a breakpoint at the `mapDetails = ...` line and check the url value, and make sure it's correct for the file location.

Comment: Update in main question post. How would I 'use filePath to read the content to NSMutableArray'?? Sorry i'm a bit of a rookie :)

Comment: I've checked the iOS directory @JamesChan and the Plist is in there. How would I load the Plist out of the Directory and put it's contents into the array?? Thanks for the help btw :)

Comment: Use `[NSURL URLWithString:filePath]` as the file URL.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63620/discussion-between-seb-oh-and-james-chen).